# How to report overlapping cell values from 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have 2 sets of timeseries (dd/mm/yyyy) potentially starting and ending at different periods. I would like to report in another cell all the overlapping dates and relative data associated with them which are present in both columns.

The picture below explains exactly what data I have and what I would like to do with it.

[image]

Selecting the 2 columns, created the variables and initiated the "foreach" loop, I don't know the code structure to perform such command.

```
Sub overlap()
Dim c As Range


For Each c In Selection
    If c.Value
Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't simple `VLOOKUP` work for this?

Comment: It would help if you could post a short sample (or images) of the initial and the resulting data. You can modify your question (post) by using the **edit** below your question (post).

Comment: @newguy VLOOKUP, INDEX (MATCH()), etc... whatever, as long as I can make this process automatic. Can't just simply record a macro because the data ranges often change..

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should do that:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub Overlap()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range, Rng2 As Range
    Dim Cell As Variant, Double As Variant

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Whatever")


    LastRow = ws.Cells(wsV.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Lastcol = ws.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'Your entire range, here in column A    
    Rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    ' Loop through each cell of the Range
    For Each Cell in Rng
        'Set a new range, from the beginning of the orginal one to your current row
        Set Rng2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1), ws.Cells(Cell.Row,1))
        With Rng2
        Set Double = .Find(Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        ' If double is not nothing you've found the value of the current cell
        ' Meaning there's more than one
        If Not Double Is Nothing Then
          'Here you found a duplicate value - Do what you need to do
        End If  
      End With
    Next Cell     

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, will test it tomorrow :)